# External HDD on bash on ubuntu on windows

Tags: windows, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hfs+

How do I access an external hard drive through bash-on-Ubuntu-on-windows. It doesn't seem to appear in either `/media`, `/mnt` or `/dev`, which seem the common places that people say to look for them in Ubuntu systems.

Note: the hard drive is HFS+ formatted: I use Paragon's HFS+ for windows and have already done an `apt-get install hfsprogs` which I think should allow the Linux part to read the HFS+ format. I have also tried with normal USB sticks, no of which seemed to appear anywhere.

The drive does appear in `/cygdrive` in cygwin, but when I navigate to cygdrive in bash it doesn't appear. Clearly it is not properly mounted there, but is some form of symbolical link that bash cannot see.

I'm not really sure if this is a Linux or a Windows issue, but there doesn't seem to be anything from Microsoft about it, though I realise it is early days for them.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Apologies. Thanks for taking the time to look anyway

Comment: Well MS positions WSL primarily as a developer tool. So you could make a case that this is not off topic.

Comment: This is not off-topic. From [Learn about the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) – the very first sentence on that page: "The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run Linux environments".

Comment: @KennyEvitt: It is off-topic.  "WSL lets gamers run Linux environments", "WSL lets sysadmins run Linux environments", "WSL lets athletes run LInux environments", "WSL lets chemists run Linux environments", "WSL lets filmmakers run Linux environments" are all true, without making the Microsoft statement untrue.  But the condition of "a practical problem **unique** to software development" is not met here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ubuntu on Windows on the current build (Build 14393, a.k.a. anniversary update) doesn't support accessing external drive. This feature is on their backlog for future consideration.

Source: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13355724-unable-to-access-usb-devices-from-bash

Edit: Mounting removable drives are supported since Build 16176. [1][2]

1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001783/643011
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

Comment: Ah that would be why then - thanks!

Comment: Solved now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44001783/643011

Comment: Starting Windows build 22000, things are a bit more easy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk